# WP_Query & Duplicate entries

Tags: wp-query, loop, query

I am currently using this code in order to get the latest three posts of my website, successfully and with no issues:

```
$posts = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => 3 ) );
```

but I want to switch to wp_query.

I tried a simple wp_query call in order to show tha latest 3 articles posted on my website:

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 3
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And also used this PHP code in order to provide an output of this wp_query:

```
<?php 
while ($posts -> have_posts()) : $posts -> the_post();
foreach( $posts as $p ): ?>
<?php the_title(); ?><br>
<?php endforeach; endwhile; ?>
```

But in the end it failed. Instead of having an output list of:

**First post title

Second post title

Third post title**

I do get an output list of:

**First post titleFirst post titleFirst post titleSecond post titleSecond post titleSecond post titleThird post titleThird post titleThird post title**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be a `foreach` loop inside the `while`. The `while` loops over posts, so you don't need another `foreach`. The `while` loop in this context is what WordPress calls "The Loop".

See the section of documentation for The Loop on secondary queries [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#creating-secondary-queries-and-loops).

So your loop should look like this:

```
<?php while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?><br>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```